# Do a Page Break on the same page of SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I want to show 50 rows in one page of the SSRS Report. But I want to show these 50 rows in two columns of 25 rows each. Is there a way to do a page break on the same page or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: How many records? One way would be to loop through the data and add a group id in SQL per 50 records  eg. recs 1 - 50 = Grp 1, 51-100 = Grp 2. The Grp would be a hidden column in the report and the Group would be setup to throw a page on change in group

Comment: There is no limit of number of records that this report will have to handle. But I want to show 50 records on one page with 25records in each column. So each page will have 2 columns of 25 records and there will be multiple pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to arrange your data, you will need to have two separate tables each configured to only show 25 rows sorted so that it displayes as you require (Read across then down or down one table then the other?)

One way to do this would be to create a hidden row group as @MiguelH suggested in their comment that has two levels to it, so you group into 50s and 25s along the lines of:

```
Row #   -  Group 1  -  Group 2
  1           1          1
  2           1          1
....
 24           1          1
 25           1          1
 26           1          2
 27           1          2
....
 49           1          2
 50           1          2
 51           2          1
 52           2          1
....
 74           2          1
 75           2          1
 76           2          2
 77           2          2
....
 98           2          2
 99           2          2
100           3          1
101           3          1
```

You can then set a page break after your table group, displaying all records with a `Group 2` value of `1` in the first table and a `Group 2` value of `2` in your second table on the same page.

Comment: I tried this already and this will create complications in the later phase when I will have to color code based on the row number. Thats why I was thinking to create only one table as it will reduce lot of complications and dependency in the later phases.

Comment: @Programmermid  How does this cause problems with the colour coding?

Comment: There is a entire different logic running in other part of the report where based on some value in other datasets I will have to check the row number here and will have to color code accordingly. So for example if I use two different tables then 25th row of first table and 25th row of the second table will be different.Which will be incorrect. Thats why I want to add only one table.

Comment: @Programmermid  Can you not either do a `ROW_NUMBER()` in your SQL dataset, or simply calculate what the row number would have been from the `Group 1` and `Group 2` values?

Comment: It is possible but I will have to change lot of existing logic, Is there any other way to achieve this instead of adding ids and adding two tables? Can we add a parent group which will add a page break after 50 rows or something because in the current scenario I am able to split the table its just I am not able to add a page break after 50 rows. Its creating a third column when there are more than 50 rows!

Comment: @Programmermid  Not that I'm aware of.